# Are there any Eclipse language IDEs -plugins- that use JavaCC?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javacc

I'm using JavaCC to create a language plugin for Eclipse and I wanted to know if there are any stable language IDEs for Eclipse that use JavaCC to create their AST representations and Lexer/Parser files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any stable ones, however, the [Eclipse IMP project](http://www.eclipse.org/imp/) supports creating IDE using any parser generator. Sadly, the project does not seem especially active (the last release is almost a year old), and documentation is a bit scarce.

However, it features a half-working example (crated with LPG), that I believe it could be adapted for JavaCC as well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a Google search for

"import org.eclipse" "import org.javacc"

hoping to find a web page with the text of a .java file from some plugin that included both. No results came up. Nonetheless there may well be a plugin that uses JavaCC, but completely segregates the code that depends on JavaCC from code that depends on Eclipse. Hmm.